# What controls the behavior of OpenGL when drawing triangle strips?

Tags: opengl, geometry

So I do know how to draw multiple triangles using `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS)`. What I want to understand is how OpenGL decides which vertex (out of the first three provided) to use as the starting vertex for all remaining triangles to be drawn? And is there a way to make it select a different starting vertex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GL selects the last *two* vertices specified as the first *two* vertices of the second triangle, which is completed by the *fourth* vertex.

So, you need to change the order you specify vertices.

From the Manual: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html#name2

> GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP : Draws a series of triangles (three-sided polygons) using vertices v0, v1, v2, then v2, v1, v3 (note the order), then v2, v3, v4, and so on.